# Next.js with Authjs v5 - not getting user info server-side

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm attempting to implement an API route following the guidance here: https://authjs.dev/guides/upgrade-to-v5#authenticating-server-side under the API Route tab.

The code I have is a little expanded from the sample there:

```
import { auth } from "../../../auth"
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next"
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';


export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    try {
        const session = await auth(req, res)
        if (session) {
            console.log(session.user)
            return NextResponse.json({status: "OK"})
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
    }
    console.log("No session")
    return NextResponse.json({status: "ERR"})
}
```

I'm stuck on a couple of things:

- session.user isn't being populated by the auth() call. session is set if the user's logged in and not set if they're not, but I'm at a loss as to how to retrieve information about the currently logged in user.
- there's some weirdness around NextApiResponse which I don't understand - if I return res.json(..) or res.status(..) then I get an error: TypeError: res.status is not a function.

Any and all help gratefully received.